# SwiftUI How to Remove TabViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

i've created a TabView for my photos collection. But i confused how can i remove this TabView controller

[image]

Thank you for everyone who answered my question

Comment: Do you want to remove it, or just hide the dots? How are you adding the TabViewController?

Comment: @koen i'm sorry, i mean just hide the dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your TabView:

```
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```